# Direcionamento para uma solução em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Olá, bom dia galera!

Sou iniciante em javascript e gostaria de saber o que posso usar em javascript para resolver a seguinte solução:

Em um texto ao clicar em qualquer palavra eu tenha a opção de quatro cores para colorir ela.

Obrigado!

Comment: A resposta curta é sim.

Comment: Basicamente eventos e manipulação do DOM. Com o evento você saberá quando o texto for clicado, com a manipulação do DOM você conseguirá exibir as opções de cor e colorir o texto. Boa sorte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este, exemplo que eu criei para você é bem, simples, provalvemente é o que você quer.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  
    #mysection {
      width: 600px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      padding: 50px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    #mytitle {
      text-align: center;
    }

    #myparagraph {
      text-align: justify;
    }

    #mycolor {
      width: 133px;
      height: 27px;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
    }

    #mycolor > div {
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      float: left;
    }

    #black {
      background-color: black;
    }

    #red {
      background-color: red;
    }

    #green {
      background-color: green;
    }

    #yellow {
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    #exit {
      width: 25px;
      height: 27px;
    }
  
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
<section id="mysection">
  <h1 id="mytitle">JavaScript</h1>
  <p id="myparagraph">
    JavaScript, frequentemente abreviado como JS, é uma linguagem de programação interpretada de alto nível, caracterizada também, 
    como dinâmica, fracamente tipada, prototype-based e multi-paradigma.[2] Juntamente com HTML e CSS, o JavaScript é uma das três
    principais tecnologias da World Wide Web. <a href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript">Winkipedia</a>
  </p>
</section>

<div id="mycolor">
  <div id="black"></div>
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
  <button id="exit" type="button">X</button>
</div>

<script>

var p = window.document.querySelector("#myparagraph");
var myColor = window.document.querySelector("#mycolor");

var black = window.document.querySelector("#black");
var red = window.document.querySelector("#red");
var green = window.document.querySelector("#green");
var yellow = window.document.querySelector("#yellow");
var exit = window.document.querySelector("#exit");

p.addEventListener("click", function() {
  myColor.style.display = "block";
});

black.addEventListener("click", function() {
  p.style.color = "black";
});

red.addEventListener("click", function() {
  p.style.color = "red";
});

green.addEventListener("click", function() {
  p.style.color = "green";
});

yellow.addEventListener("click", function() {
  p.style.color = "yellow";
});

exit.addEventListener("click", function() {
  myColor.style.display = "none";
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

bom, na parte javascript eu declarei varias variáveis `p, myColor, black, red, green, yellow, exit`. Cada uma dessas variáveis tem um valor, este valor nada mais nada menos do que uma referência aos nomes `id` no html. Isso é o mesmo que selecionar um elemento no css e depois aplicar propriedades a ele. depois cada uma dessas variáveis `p, black, red, green, yellow, exit`. Recebem um evento usando o `addEventListener()` esse evento é um evento de click ou seja quando você clicar no elemento. Em seguida quando o evento de click ocorrer irar disparar um `function(){}` que é uma função anônima(uma função que não tem nome) você poderia chamar uma função nomeada(com nome) mais não o fiz, porque se não o código iria ficar bem grande. Dentro da função tem os devidos códigos a serem executados, no `p` ele tem `myColor.style.display = "block";` ou seja a `div` com `id="mycolor"` no html irar ficar em formato de `block` ela irar aparecer, já que no css nois deixamos ela como `display: none`. Depois no `black` você tem `p.style.color = "black";` ou sejá o parágrafo irar ficar preto e isso irar acontecer também com `red, green, yellow`, apenas as cores são diferentes e por ultimo no `exit`, tem `myColor.style.display = "none";` ou seja a nossa `div` que possui o `id="mycolor"` irar desaparecer quando eu clicar no `button` com o `id="exit"`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Leandro. Vou juntar sua ajuda com o que estou pesquisando e realizar o que estou tentando fazer. \0/

Comment: De nada amigo espero ter ajudado!